# Effective simulation of compound poisson process in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to simulate a huge bunch of compound poisson processes in Matlab on a very fine grid so I am looking to do it most effectively.

I need to do a lot of simulations on the same random numbers but with parameters changing so it is practical to draw the uniforms and normals beforehand even though it means i have to draw a lot more than i will probably need and won't matter much because it will only need to be done once compared to in the order `500*n` repl times the actual compound process generation.

My method is the following:
Let `T` be for how long i need to simulate and N the grid points, then my grid is:

```
t=linspace(1,T,N);
```

Let nrepl be the number of processes i need then I simulate

```
P=poissrnd(lambda,nrepl,1); % Number of jumps for each replication
U=(T-1)*rand(10000,nrepl)+1; % Set of uniforms on (1,T) for jump times
N=randn(10000,nrepl); % Set of normals for jump size
```

Then for replication `j`:

```
Poiss=P(j); % Jumps for replication
Uni=U(1:Poiss,j);% Jump times
Norm=mu+sigma*N(1:Poiss,j);% Jump sizes
```

**Then this I guess is where I need your advice, I use this one-liner but it seems very slow:**

```
CPP_norm=sum(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@gt,t,Uni),Norm),1);
```

In the inner for each jump it creates a series of same length as `t` with `0` until jump and then `1` after, multiplying this will create a grid with zeroes until jump has arrived and then the jump size and finally adding all these will produce the entire jump process on the grid.

How can this be done more effectively?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I will do that when writing code from now on!

Comment: How large is `lambda`? For `lambda` much smaller than `numel(t)` your resulting vector (before applying the sum) contains many duplicates. Maybe calculating these values only once can speed up the process.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I can't think up a neater way of doing this even though you are right - do you have a suggestion?. I think numel(t) is about 80 times the usual number of jumps (this is a rough estimate) so I guess there would be something to gain.

Comment: what are the dimensions of `t` `Uni` and `Norm`?

Comment: `t` is usually of length 157092, but for some applications up to 50 times as long. And `nrepl` in the order 50.

Comment: I came across another cause of inefficiency, you are generating double random numbers, but finally your discretize them to indices in a matrix. Try to generate the indices directly using random integers.

Comment: So you mean, generate instead a discrete random variable of dimension the same as my `t` and then one can just change those indices. That is a brilliant idea!

Comment: Okay, what is the good way of handling two jumps in the same index? I can only think off slow ways of handling it.

Comment: How does one effectively handle if two jumps fall in the same index?

Comment: @Henrik: My code should be able to handle this, if not please add sime details. Do you know that `sparse` uses a sum if fields are defined duplicate? Check out `sparse([42,42],[23,23],[1,2])`

Comment: Ahh.. that just makes your code even more genius. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing with `CPP_norm`, but if it is possible to work with the derivation you have much less data:

```
diffCPP_norm=bsxfun(@times,sparse(diff(bsxfun(@gt,t,Uni),1,2)),Norm);
```

Using `CPP_norm=full(cumsum(diffCPP_norm))` you can recreate your original data, but then you lose the advantage.

Comment: This seems interesting, I am not used to sparse matrices, but I will check it out. Is there a good way  to "sum the first dimension out" still (i.e. the equivalent of above) so that I get the "sparse vector" corresponding that would compare differencing my final result? It's hard to explain properly, but I hope you get my explanation.

Comment: Ahh. it seems sum works, I will check if this gives a good speed increase :)

Comment: I've been able to use this and simulating indices instead speeds up the process immensely, thanks for the great input :)